# Action-class method is not called from struts2

Tags: java, struts2

This is a very odd error that I have but I have been struggle with this for a week now.
I have a web application that worked fine on Jboss4 but when I moved it to Jboss6 all hell broke loose.
Check out the following code

list.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" %>
<s:if test="payments != null">
  <div id="payManuallyDialog" class="defaultDialog" style="height: 150px; width: 300px;">
   <s:form onsubmit="return false;" action="PayManually" namespace="/authorized/payments" name="PayManuallyForm" id="PayManuallyForm" cssStyle="height: 100%;">
     <s:url id="payManuallyURL" action="PayManually" namespace="/authorized/payments" />
     <sx:div id="PayManuallyPanel" cssStyle="height: 100%;" formId="PayManuallyForm" formFilter="filterFields" href="%{payManuallyURL}" theme="ajax" listenTopics="view_pay" showLoadingText="false">
     </sx:div>
     <s:hidden key="paymentID" value="" />
     <s:hidden key="command" value="" />
   </s:form>
  </div>
</s:if>
```

With a javascript function at the top

```
function filterFields(field) {
   return field.name == "paymentID" || field.name == "command" || field.name == "payDate";
}
function pay(id) {
   document.PayManuallyForm.paymentID.value = id;
   document.PayManuallyForm.command.value = "view";
   dojo.event.topic.publish("view_pay");
   openModalDialog("payManuallyDialog");
   document.PayManuallyForm.command.focus();
}
function cancel() {
   document.PayManuallyForm.paymentID.value = "";
   document.PayManuallyForm.command.value = "";
   closeModalDialog("payManuallyDialog");
}
function save(id) {
   document.PayManuallyForm.paymentID.value = id;
   document.PayManuallyForm.command.value = "save";
   dojo.event.topic.publish("view_pay");
   closeModalDialog("payManuallyDialog");
}
```

payManually.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<div class="dialogWrapper">
   <div class="dialogTitle">
      <s:text name="label.header" />:&nbsp;<s:text name="pay.paymentID" />&nbsp;<s:property value="ID" />
   </div>
   <div class="dialogContent">
      <s:date name="payDate" id="payDateId" format="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <s:text name="payman.date" />&nbsp;<s:textfield name="payDate" value="%{payDateId}" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="dialogFooter">
   <a class="tableLink" href="javascript: save(<s:property value='ID'/>);"><img border="0" src="/gfx/active.gif" />&nbsp;<s:text name="label.save" /></a>
   &nbsp;<a class="tableLink" href="javascript: cancel();"><img border="0" src="/gfx/inactive.gif" />&nbsp;<s:text name="label.cancel" /></a>
</div>
```

My struts.xml

```
<action name="PayManually" class="paymentActions" method="payManually">
   <result name="input">/WEB-INF/authorized/payments/payManually.jsp</result>
   <result name="success">/WEB-INF/authorized/payments/payManually.jsp</result>
   <result name="error" type="tiles">**error-page**</result>
</action>
```

And my action-class

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public String payManually() {
    System.out.println("Command == "+command);
    try {
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("payManually called with paymentID" + paymentID + ", command=" + command + ", payDate=" + payDate);
        }
        if (paymentID != null && command != null) {
            if (command.equals("view")) {
**** Do some things ****
            } else if (command.equals("save") && payDate != null) {
**** Do some things ****
    } catch (ServerException serverException) {
        serverException.printStackTrace();
        addActionError(serverException.getMessage());
    }
    return (!hasActionErrors()) ? SUCCESS : ERROR;
}
```

I have all the getters and setters.

As you can see I set the command variable in my javascript-code. This works for the pay(id) function, command is set and the id is set. As I press the save-button in my payManually.jsp page the javascript function save(id) is called and all the variables is set but my actionclass method is not called!

My log shows following lines

> 2013-05-07 15:31:17:462 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-1] INFO actions.payments.PaymentActions - payManually - payManually called with paymentIDnull, command=, payDate=null
>
> 2013-05-07 15:31:17:462 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-1] INFO actions.payments.PaymentActions - payManually - payManually called with paymentIDnull, command=, payDate=null
>
> 2013-05-07 15:31:20:103 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-1] INFO actions.payments.PaymentActions - payManually - payManually called with paymentID2846, command=view, payDate=null
>
> 2013-05-07 15:31:20:103 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-1] INFO actions.payments.PaymentActions - payManually - payManually called with paymentID2846, command=view, payDate=null

What am I doing wrong?

Please help me, because I'm really stuck and Google hasn't been much help

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Why the downvote? Really that bad type of question?

Comment: The problem *may* be related to the fact that your form is inside your modalDialog, and you are closing the dialog (maybe dojo has not finished yet...)? Btw there are a lot of anti-patterns here, the biggest: for two different actions, you should use one of the following way: **two different Struts2 Actions**, or **one single Struts2 Action with two different methods**. Setting a parameter in page and reading it inside a single method splitting the logic there is the same as not using Struts2 at all :/

Comment: Thank you I'll look into this. It's not me who has written the code, it just landed on my desk so i'm quite lost in this. Not used to Struts at all. But now I might have some thing to go on, so thank you for your input.